# Laravel grouping different colors and sizes

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on an eCommerce website using Laravel and I'm really stuck on this matter.

Every product with a different color or size has to be stored as a product in the database. So, for example, we offer some T-shirts available in black and white and sizes M, L, XL there are 6 products for the t-shirt in the database:

1. T-shirt black M
2. T-shirt black L
3. T-shirt black XL
4. T-shirt red M
5. T-shirt red L
6. T-shirt red XL

We have a table that is related to the product and is formatted as follows:

| id | product_id | attribute | value | group_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -- | ---------- | color | black | -------- |
| -- | ---------- | color | red | -------- |
| -- | ---------- | size | m | -------- |
| -- | ---------- | size | l | -------- |
| -- | ---------- | size | xl | -------- |

In controller to get the data we use these queries

```
    $colorGroup = ProductGroup::with('product')->where('group_id', '=', $product->group_uid)->where('attribute', '=', 'color')->get();
    $sizeGroup = ProductGroup::with('product')->where('group_id', '=', $product->group_uid)->where('attribute', '=', 'size')->get();
```

Now if you visit the product page for the T-shirt black M we want to show the other options for the sizes and colors as well and the current product color and size selected. For example:

Pick a color:
black (selected), red

Pick a size:
M (selected), L, XL

Comment: Is it an api or blade project?

Comment: Please could you make the question you're asking a little clearer, I'm not sure what question you're asking, or what error you're seeing.